# Problems with RegSetValueEx

Tags: registry

I am using Qt to create some program that edits the registry, take a look:

```
 HKEY hKey;
char lpData[] = "itworks";

RegSetValueExA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\SAMP", 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)&lpData, size(lpData));
```

*error: C2660: 'QWidget::size' : function does not take 1 arguments*.

As to why it gives me that error I don't know. It seems to be pointing at the Reserved part of the function (the 0 before ", REG_SZ"). If anyone can help me out it would be awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the answer to my problem. First of all, you must include advapi32.lib. Second, you must always convert any kind of QString to WCHAR in order to work with RegSetValue.